# The property imageUrl is not recognized by Schema.org vocabulary

Tags: schema

I am facing this issue. after the audit search showed this error here is my [website](https://www.beststeamiron.io) can anybody help me to solve this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aFNa.png)

Answer (score 0):

there is no such property as `imageUrl`, it should be just `image`

so, in the `Article` markup, replace

```
"imageUrl": "https://www.beststeamiron.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Best-steam-iron.jpg",
```

with:

```
"image": "https://www.beststeamiron.io/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Best-steam-iron.jpg",
```